# WP_Query: Fetch posts that are in (category1 and not in category2), OR posts that are not in cagegory1

Tags: posts, categories, wp-query

I have two categories that will always stay the same. They are called "Events" and "Show on frontpage". The latter is a child category to Events.

What i want to do is, when fetching posts (using WP_Query), check if the post is in the Events category. If it is, and it is NOT in the "Show on frontpage" category, don't fetch the post at all.

Scenarios:

```
- post is in Events but NOT in Show on frontpage:     Don't fetch post
- post is in Events AND in Show on frontpage:         Fetch post
- post is NOT in Events:                              Fetch post
```

The goal is to achieve the functionality only using WP_Query. Maybe it's possible using some special `category__in` or `category__not_in` queries or something. The trick is to kind of have an `if` statement inside the query, because there are three possible scenarios.

Ideas?

Comment: An if statement in your loop would prob be the easiest.  I think the last scenario is what really throws it off. If you didn't have the third scenario you could use the category__and argument.If you switched your show on front page setting to meta data instead of a taxonomy you could use something like $args = array('meta_query' => array( array('key'=>'show_on_front','value'=>'your_active_value','compare'=>'=')));

Comment: I'm using an if statement right now, but that doesn't work quite as i want it to. If the first scenario is met (don't fetch), i just skip the post using `continue;`. The problem is, if i have set wordpress to display 10 posts per page, and it skips some posts, then i will end up with less than 10 posts whenever the don't fetch scenario is met. This is a bigger issue than it seems, because i'm loading more posts using ajax, on some pages it only fetches one post per "load", so if that post is skipped, the script will assume there are no more posts, and return nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go, try a tax_query instead http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

```
...
'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array( 'event','show_on_front' ),
        'operator' => 'AND',
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array( 'event' ),
        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
   )
)
```

Comment: Hmm, code seems to be perfectly valid, but i'm not getting the correct results. It's as if it just ignores the query entirely. Have a look at my entire $config that i send into WP_Query: http://pastebin.com/KLFj5JBS Do you see *anything* that might cause it to fail? Slugs are correct. I'll take a deeper look at it tomorrow, time to go home now.

Comment: I think my last edit should do the trick

Comment: I think the original 'relation' => 'OR' was correct.

Comment: Still not entirely sure what caused it to not work in the beginning, might have been the fact that i had show_on_front as a sub-category to event. It works fine now, thank you!

Comment: Tax query can also take an "include_children" boolean argument.  If you wanted to keep it as a sub category.